# python crashes(?) when trying to create a list

Tags: python, list, crash

When I have been trying to run this code in python a python tab opens but immidietly shuts down. when I run other programs it works just fine. I have no clue what the problem might be.

The code:

```
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
list1 = [9]
while b != 9:
    print(list1)
    list1.append = (c, d)
    b += 1
    e += 1
    c += 200
    if e == 3:
        e = 0
        d += 200
        c = 0
input()
```

Comment: We'd need to see the error say to for sure, but `list1.append = (c, d)`, should be just `list1.append(c, d)` at the very least.

Comment: Use `list1.append([c, d])` and why are you taking `input`from the user at the end of the code?

Comment: @Ahmet That's common to prevent the console from closing when the script isn't run from the command line directly. The user needs to press enter for the program to end.

Comment: I thought half of the code was pasted. I thought there will be more code

Comment: I changed the append command to "list1.append((c, d))" and now it works just fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.append = (c, d)
```

What did you try to achieve? Append is a method of the list. If you wanted to add those elements at the end of the list, then:

```
list1.append(c)
list1.append(d)
```

Is one of the proper way of doing this.

Comment: I used "list1.append((c, d)" and now it works. Wanted to create a list of coordinates.